# Is batching a way to avoid local minima?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

That is my question: is batching one way to prevent the model from falling in a local minima? What is the difference between `bach=1` and `batch=32` in those terms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no rather the opposite. gradient descent -ie using whole dataset to compute gradient suffers from local minima.
taking a random sub sample (minibatch) can avoid local minima because you are adding noise- which effectively changes the error surface possibly removing the local minima (or introducing new one).  However, too much noise (eg batch =1) and you are just solving for one sample and then undoing effects to solve for the next (depending on learning rate).

a Minibatch eg 32 therefore is a compromise. In addition, there is a computational issue, using minibatch instead of full batch can give you almost the same gradient as using the full batch at much less computational effort. ( law of large numbers effect - std dev decreases with sqrt(samples)).
so if my gradient error is ~ x with 32 samples, then i need 3200 samples to get gradient error ~ 1/10 x.

Comment: I've seen the claim in your first paragraph almost every time a question like this answered, but I can't find a definitive source for it. Do you have any references?

Comment: “std dev decreases with sqrt(samples)” – uh, that argument doesn't really work if the input space has much higher dimension than the number of samples.

Comment: @mhdadk - You should be able to find it in any neural net text book.  The error surface is not convex in a multlayer network (even with linear neurons! https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6120.pdf), therefore you can have the existence of local minima.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't see why it doesn't work.  In any case CNNs use weight sharing so the effective input space is smaller, no

Comment: so by using batch size, a model will have higher probabilities of avoiding local minimums and not throw to the can what it learned in previous iterations, right? @seanv507

Comment: @noober yes exactly